# Page Prev/Next of PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am writing a simple script using PHP/MySQL for records and I saved records and it's working perfectly.

My problem is that I need to show 4 records only and have a pager to go to next/prev pages.

Can someone give me a code please?

Here is my code:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM products Where username='$_SESSION[username]' LIMIT 0, 4");


while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td width='25%'>". $row['serial'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td><img width='65' height='65' src='upload/".$row['image']."'></td>";
  echo "<td width='25%'>". $row['arrive'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td width='25%'>". $row['size']; "</td>";  
  echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you have to calculate the starting point and then use it in your SQL query.

Have a look at this code:

```
// pagination
$total_results = mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($con,"SELECT `username` FROM products Where username='$_SESSION[username]' "));

if(!isset($page_number))
  $page_number = (int)$_GET['page'] <= 0 ? 1 : (int)$_GET['page']; // grab the page number

$perpage = 4; // number of elements perpage


if($page_number > ceil($total_results/$perpage))
  $page_number = ceil($total_results/$perpage);


$start = ($page_number - 1) * $perpage;

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM products Where username='$_SESSION[username]' LIMIT $start, $perpage");
```

Also as you can see the total number of pages is `ceil($total_results/$perpage)` so you can use that and `$page_number` to decide when to show next/prev

Comment: can more explain please i am trying to use this code .. but i see no differince

Comment: which part is unclear ? you get the total results, you grab the current page, and you calculate the starting point

Comment: its working with me now, and i can see pages its really perfect but i need a simple help from you echo '<a href="http://website.com/yourPage.php?page=2">Next page</a>'; i want when click it first one it +1 and when click it again +1 etc.. how make it please..

Comment: you mean `echo "<a href='page.php?page=".($page_number+1)."'>Next</a>";` ?

Answer (score 0):

Set the 0 in your Limit clause to a variable and increment by 4

```
//$_POST['limit']=0,4,8,12....
$start = $_POST['limit'];
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM products Where username='$_SESSION[username]' LIMIT $start, 4");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if (!isset($_GET['page'])))
{
    $page = 1;
}
else
{
    $page = (int)$_GET['page'];
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM products Where username='$_SESSION[username]' LIMIT " . ($page - 1) * 4 . ", 4");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td width='25%'>". $row['serial'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td><img width='65' height='65' src='upload/".$row['image']."'></td>";
    echo "<td width='25%'>". $row['arrive'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td width='25%'>". $row['size']; "</td>";  
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

echo '<br/>';
echo '<a href="http://website.com/yourPage.php?page=2">Next page</a>';
?>
```

Comment: Be careful, this code takes parameters from the URL and puts them into the SQL query without sanitation. It leaves it wide open to SQL Injection attack. Never put code like this on a live server, bad things will happen.

Comment: Try `$page = (int)$_GET['page'];`. And if it's not working please show more code.